# Open source graph database

Tags: java, database, graph, nosql

I need graph database for my project. I want to perform shortest path operation on the graph. I searched google and found neo4j, InfoGrid and sones. I am not sure which one performs the best.

Neo4j is insisting on transaction for read queries also, so I am worried it will cause delays. I want high performance graph database engine. It will be awesome if it can support shortest path also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with [@Reinderien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735591/open-source-graph-database/3737217#3737217), you should bench these products. But I would also add [OrientDB](http://code.google.com/p/orient/) in the mix. Quoting its author in [this comment](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/05/06/that-no-sql-thing-graph-databases.aspx#40002):

> I'm working to OrientDB. It's a NoSQL
>   hybrid document-graph dbms with
>   special operators for graph
>   operations. The main difference is
>   that you can query it using SQL
>   language with some extension like:
>
> ```
> select from People where friends TRAVERSE(1,7) (name = 'Ayende' and surname = 'Rahien')
> ```
>
> This means get all the people that
>   have any relationship of friends with
>   you up to the 7th level of separation.

According to its website, the performances looks pretty decent. Worth the look at least.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can pay attention at [Flockdb](http://github.com/twitter/flockdb) too.

Comment: FYI Flockdb was used by Twitter and later donated to open source community. Another good thing is that it is based on SCALA .....

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately there is a common interface for most of them: [Blueprints](http://wiki.github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints). On top of it there are a lot of technologies such as the Gremlin language and REST access to the graph. Visit [Tinkerpop](http://www.tinkerpop.com) to know more.

About benchmarks there is a work-in-progress project called [graphdb-bench](http://github.com/tinkerpop/graphdb-bench) (always by Tinkerpop), but AFAIK is in development.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test out all three and apply a benchmark for your particular data? Otherwise it's difficult to say which one would perform the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.1 you can read data without using a transaction in Neo4j. In case you want to read uncommitted data though, you can only do that from inside the same transaction (and obviously need a transaction in the first place). More information on transactions is found in the [Neo4j wiki](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Transactions).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at AgensGraph and its perfomance.  `https://bitnine.net/agensgraph/`

AgensGraph supports "Shortest path" as well and you can use it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Nebula Graph(0) is Modern, Open Source(1), Scalable(to a huge scale), Performant, you can choose between 3 replicas and 1 replica.
It supports `FIND PATH`(2)

(0) https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula

(1) https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula#licensing

(2) https://docs.nebula-graph.io/2.5.1/3.ngql-guide/16.subgraph-and-path/2.find-path/

```
nebula> FIND SHORTEST PATH FROM "player102" TO "team204" OVER *;
+--------------------------------------------+
| path                                       |
+--------------------------------------------+
| <("player102")-[:serve@0 {}]->("team204")> |
+--------------------------------------------+
```